# Listening events and Updating page without Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am finding a specific logical problem a tad bit difficult. My problem is like this:

I send a PUT request from inside a controller via some factory methods. I want to update the data without any kind of page-refresh. for eg. $state.go() or $location.path() etc. For POST and DEL, I've done something like this:

```js
$scope.$on('itemRemoved', (e, item) => {
    vm.allItems = vm.allItems.filter(item => {
        item._id !== item._id)
       })
    })
$scope.$on('itemAdded', (e, item) => vm.allItems.push(item))
      
// For PUT, I want to do something like this..

 $scope.$on('itemUpdt', (e, item) => {
    vm.allItems.push(item).findIndex('index of oldItem').splice('exclude oldItem index').join(',')
  })
```

'item' is an array of object returned from ajax call. The above method didn't work for me. Is there something wrong or any better ways to solve this problem? Thanks for reading :)

Comment: What kind of object is `vm.allItems`? Just a regular array?

Comment: yes it's an array of objects.my bad not mentioning it.

Comment: No problem. I assumed that was the case, just had to be certain.

Comment: You likely have errors in your console. Let us know what those are.

Comment: You can combine the closures from first two events to achieve 3rd, but it won't be the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$scope.$on('itemUpdt', (e, item) => {
    vm.allItems = vm.allItems.filter(item => {
        item._id !== item._id;
    });
    vm.allItems.push(item);
});
```

Or

```
const findIndex = (array, item) => {
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]._id == item._id){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1
};

$scope.$on('itemUpdt', (e, item) => {
    var indexToRemove = findIndex(vm.allItems, item);
    vm.allItems.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    vm.allItems.push(item);
});
```

Comment: oh that's really clean. i filter out both old and new item but later concat the new one. thanks a lot :)

Comment: Check again I have added another way.

Comment: yea the second one is what i originally planned to do. new es6 and fp methods have made me lazy. btw you have a typo in line 3 (array[0])

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript function `push()` actually returns the new length of the array, not the array itself. So calling `findIndex()` on the return value of `push()` may be what's causing your issue.

Comment: i'm directly modifying the array by passing 'item' so it's still type array tho

Comment: Are you sure? According to the [JavaScript specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) `vm.allItems.push(item)` should return the new length of the array - not the actual array.

Comment: yea you are right. i meant to do concat() but did push() . thanks for the heads up :)